# C++, to return a various class instance how to create a template?

Tags: c++, generics

I'm trying to make a function that returns "vector"

```
vector<Class A,B or C> _Class123::getVectorList();
```

or
    `vector<struct A,B or c> _class123::getDataList();`

Various classes are three classes that I define.
depending on the logic, this function should return one of those.

in C++, is it possible with template?

Comment: You shouldn't use [reserved names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783) for your types.

Answer (score 3):

You sound like you want a discriminated union, in which case you might want to look into something like Boost.Variant:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/variant.html

Your function would then be:

```
std::vector<boost::variant<A,B,C> > _Class123::getVectorList();
```

Comment: Just for curiosity: Is there a [tag:c++11] standard solution for this problem?

Comment: Thank you, but I couldn't use other lib. Is there any other way without ext.lib?

Comment: @user1060039: The other way is to write your own discriminated union. There's no standard type for that. But there's no sensible reason not to use this Boost library; it's header-only, with an unrestrictive license.

Comment: If you're not allowed to use boost', simply implement the variant data type yourself, this has gotten a lot easier in C++11 due to the relaxation of union.

Comment: @g-makulik: No, there's no equivalent of Boost.Variant in the C++ Standard Library unfortunately (yet, at least).